# Setting Background to Imageview

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, imageview

I am creating a dynamically Imageview.

```
ImageView btnSend = new ImageView (this);
```

I need to put a layout that contains the states of the images, this is the xml:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<selector
      xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item
           android: state_focused = "true"
           android: state_pressed = "false"
           android: drawable = "@ drawable/button_state3" />
      <item
           android: state_focused = "true"
           android: state_pressed = "true"
           android: drawable = "@ drawable/button_state2" />
      <item
           android: state_focused = "false"
           android: state_pressed = "true"
           android: drawable = "@ drawable/button_state2" />
      <item
           android: drawable = "@ drawable/button_state1" />
</ selector>
```

I tested with setBackgroundResource property, but does not work.

how do I assign this layout to Imageview?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have created in this XML (BTW remove the spaces after @) is a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) not a Layout as you mentioned.
Consequently, use [ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mydrawable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) to set it.

Comment: And make sure it's in your drawable folder, not your layout folder.

Comment: StateListDrawable fix my problem, thanks dtmilano!!

I leave the code in the post below for users who have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that works...

```
ImageView btnEliminar = new ImageView (this);

StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();

Drawable normal = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_normal);
Drawable selected = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_selected);
Drawable pressed = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_pressed);

drawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed}, pressed);
drawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused}, selected);
drawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled}, normal);

btnEliminar.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```